# 階乗を計算する方法

Tags: mysql

最終的にやりたいのは
正規分布累積関数の表を作りたいです

そのために[誤差関数](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%AA%A4%E5%B7%AE%E9%96%A2%E6%95%B0)というのを計算する必要があって
その中に階乗の計算があるのですが MySQL の数学関数にはありません

プログラムであれば

```
retval = 1
for i in 1..n
  retval *= i
```

と簡単に書けると思うのですが MySQL ではどのように書くのが（速度的にもソース的にも）早いでしょうか

1〜N のテーブルを生成してから
exp(sum(log(n)))
を取るみたいな記事も見かけたのですが log や exp は整数演算に比べたら遥かに重そうなので無駄な気がします

こういうのは１度プログラム側にデータを取得してプログラム側で計算するしかないのでしょうか

#### 補足：

MySQL 5.7 です

#### 追記

やりたいことの詳細を書くと
平均と分散カラムを持ってる数万件の正規分布レコードに対して
現在時刻がどの累積分布の位置にあるかを計算して
特定の位置にあるレコードだけを取得するという処理を Lambda で行いたいです

wiki の「これを反復的に計算するには、以下のように定式化するのが扱い易い。」の式を使おうと思っています。（SVG なので貼れない）

外側は sum なんですが内側のループが実質階乗なのでどう書けばいいか質問した次第です。

近似式も書いてあるのですが「実軸付近の誤差関数の値について、少なくとも十進で1桁の精度」の意味がよくわからなかったのと、 級数展開でも「最初の方の幾つかの項だけでよい近似が得られ、テイラー展開よりも収束が早い」 とあるので眼福計算を採用しました。

必要な精度は横軸が１日の分布で精度は秒あれば十分なので 1 / 24 x 3600 程度です
近似式の方でもこの精度は満たせるものなのでしょうか？

式自体は複雑ですが上記精度要件から実際は四則演算100回もない程度の軽い処理で、 
取得データは毎回数件になるというケースなので、 
ネットワークオーバーヘッドを使うより MySQL 側でやる方がメリットが大きいかなと考えました

Comment: MySQLのバージョンは8ですか？共通テーブル式(CTE)が使えるかどうかなんですが。

Comment: 5.7 です。質問にも追記しました

Comment: Stored function を使う方法でも構わないのですか？

Comment: 使ったことが使ったことがないのでわかってないんですが、クエリが終わった後にも残り続けるようなものなんでしょうか？　MySQL はチームで使ってるので許可をもらう必要はあると思います。それを使うしか得られないメリットであれば許可は降りると思いますが

Comment: 実際には[こんな感じ](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/f7zARazomGgvrXWDCZFhjo/0)になります。`CREATE FUNCTION` によって登録すると、DROP FUNCTION で削除しない限り MySQL サーバの実行中は継続的に利用可能になります。メリットは特にないですし、`bigint` 型の最大値(2^64-1)を考慮すると `factorial(20)` が限界です。

Comment: 「`CUME_DIST` が使えるようになります」って言ってMySQLのバージョンを8にあげてもらうのが一番楽そう。 http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-cume_dist-function/

Comment: 本来の目的が「正規分布累積関数の表を作りたい」あるいは「誤差関数というのを計算する」と言うのであれば、「その中に階乗の計算がある」とか言い出している点で、そもそもアプローチの方法が間違っているように思われます。もしかして級数展開された式をそのまま計算しようとしているのでしょうか? もしそうなら、0の近傍以外では事実上まともな精度は得られません。[英語版のWikiには、いくつか初等関数での近似が掲載されています](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Approximation_with_elementary_functions)から、そこら辺を調べて精度と計算時間が適切なものを見つけ出すと良いでしょう。ただし、階乗の計算というより「誤差関数」や「正規分布累積関数」自体、「１度プログラム側にデータを取得してプログラム側で計算する」方がはるかに簡単になるでしょう。現実には採用されないようなどんな苦労があってでもMySQLだけでなんとかする、という課題なんでしょうか?

Comment: 「これを反復的に計算するには、以下のように定式化するのが扱い易い。」の式を使おうと思ってました。　
外側は sum なんですが内側のループが実質階乗なのでどう書けばいいか質問した次第です。　

近似式も読んだんですが「実軸付近の誤差関数の値について、少なくとも十進で1桁の精度」の意味がよくわからなかったのと、
級数展開でも「最初の方の幾つかの項だけでよい近似が得られ、テイラー展開よりも収束が早い」
とあるのでこちらを採用しました。　

必要な精度は横軸が１日の分布で精度は秒あれば十分なので 1 / 24 x 3600 程度なのですが、
近似式の方でもこの精度は満たせるものなのでしょうか？　

「プログラム側で計算する」方がはるかに簡単　
確かにコードは簡単になるのでどちらで処理するか迷いましたが
Lambda で動かす予定なのであまり実行時間を使いたくないのと、
式自体は複雑ですが上記精度要件から実際は四則演算100回程度の軽い処理で、
数万ユーザに対してこの値をフィルターに使い、取得データは毎回数件になるというケースなので、
ネットワークオーバーヘッドを使うより MySQL 側でやる方がメリットが大きいかなと考えました

Comment: > MySQLのバージョンを8にあげてもらう　　すごく魅力的なのでチームにアプローチしてみますが、うちインフラが弱くてDBアップデートに毎回２、３人月かかるのですぐには難しそうです

Comment: 実際に書いてみたところ z が大きいと発散の方が多くて 「0の近傍以外では事実上まともな精度は得られません」でした。なので近似式の方を使ってみようと思います。

Answer (score 1):

階乗を求めるSQLです。試したのは、mysql 8.0.18.0　32bit版です。
metropolisさんのコメントにあるとおり21はエラーとなりました。

## SQL

```
set @n := 20;
select f
from (
    with recursive rc(f, i) as(
    select 1, @n
    union all
    select f * i, i-1
      from rc
     where i-1 >= 0)
    select f, i from rc
) as a
where i = 1
;
```

## 結果

```
2432902008176640000
```

KTIさんが解決したかったこととは異なる回答であることは承知していますが、
with句を使って再帰のSQLを書くときの参考になるかと考え、回答をする次第です。